# App doc library "+new" button shows Upload dialog

Tags: document-library, document

I have a SP app in which I have a document library. However, if I click on the "New" button in the library I get the pick-file-dialog where I should browse for a file (same screen as if I click the Upload button!).

I would expect the dialog where I should pick the type of file I want to create.

So I get:

[image]

where I would expect this:

[image]

On another library on the same site I do get the right menu when clicking the new doc button.

Does anyone know how to fix this? please note that I use sharepoint online. Thanks!!!

Comment: This is the default behavior. The "new" button in the ribbon is connected to the word template associated with the document library.

Comment: yes, but I see the upper screen, not the lower. How can I have the bottom picture menu appear when clicking on +new?

Comment: In the document where this menu is not showing up, are you getting the office web app preview by clicking the dots to the right of the file name?

Comment: yes I do see the Excel Online preview

Comment: And if you try to create a additional new document library just for testing if it gets the office web app menu?

Comment: Within my app I can't add another library I am afraid...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, which dialog is shown totally depends on the following setting in the Library:

Library Settings--> Advanced Settings --> Allow management of Content Types.

If "Yes" --> Upload File dialog appears
If "No"--> "Create New File" dialog appears.

To change these settings in the app itself set the EnableContentTypes="FALSE" in the library schema.xml

Answer (score 2):

For me I find that in my SharePoint 2016 setup Allow management of Content Types to No, still causes + New to give the Upload menu. I do not want the Upload menu either. I just want the +New to open my Excel XLSX default document that I have set up. I thought I was able to do something like this in the past, but maybe it was because I was doing an InfoPath Document Form Library?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the library web part, change "Toolbar Type" to "Show Toolbar".  Then the New button works, it allows you to open your template document or create a new folder.