# New Document in Document Library behavior

Tags: 2013, default

We have a page where a document library has been added as a web-part, where when clicking on the 'new document' link, pops up a dialog to upload a file as shown below.
[image: popup]

How can I change it to present the options to select an options from menu as in the next image below, i.e. I would like the menu to popup where I can select to create a new Word, Excel, etc. document or create a folder?
[image: preferred option]

Comment: Hi Johan, whether the page is of Modern Page type or classic and may i know the SharePoint version you use either on-prem or Online

Comment: I tried to re-produce the same issue in both classic and modern page though when i click new document it display the similar as you mentioned "Create a File", word document, excel etc. not sure why you get that option

Comment: Hi Vinit, thanks for the quick response. We are using SP 2013 on-prem

Comment: PS: Not sure what is meant by 'modern or classic'? Could you please elaborate/explain?

Comment: No problem, in Sharepoint 2013 onprem we dont have modern or classic. Could you please go to Library Settings. Under Advanced Settings -> Could you please see if " Allow management of content types?" is set to Yes. if it set to Yes then make to "No" you should be able to see the other options while creating the document

Comment: It is already set to 'No'. I have tried setting it to 'Yes' and then back to 'No', but still no change.

Not sure if it is relevant, but this is a secure site (https)

Comment: sorry i dont have any clue not what would be the issue. just for a thought whether any other Library also have same issue or there you can see the "Create a File", word document, excel" etc.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to try and assist Vinit. All Libraries on this site has the same issue :(

Comment: will you be able to take screen shot of Advance settings of Document Library and share with us without mentioning your SharePoint URL. may be some Farm level setting is applied to document Library or need to activate some features on site collection

Comment: Not sure how to add image when commenting but have made screen shot available @ https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0Byc2QApyN6O_WS1TQ2VLWWtIMzA

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate sharepoint with Office Web Apps in order to see these options on 'New'.
[This](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/installing-office-online-server-hooking-up-sharepoint-macchiaroli/) article will guide you.

Comment: Is it not called Office Web Apps in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

The "Create New Files" menu appears in a document library when the content types are set to "No" or off. This is found in the library settings > advanced settings > content types.

Creating new document libraries is a good way to test this as the default setting is "no" for content types. Be sure to check what content types exist in your document library before you turn it off and blow them away. Also content types and their templates will show up in the Files ribbon tab under the new document menu.

Comment: Currently I only get 'New Document' with a MS Word icon when using the Ribbon

Comment: Yes this is related to the default content type for the document library being a blank word document. Were you able to confirm what your content type setting is for the document library?

Comment: Here is another post with the same topic https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117203/app-doc-library-new-button-shows-upload-dialog

Comment: Chris G, yes, it is set to No

Comment: So if you create a new library do you see the 'new document' menu you are looking for? perhaps the library you brought up in this post is just broken so perhaps it would be best to move your content to a new one instead?